# How did google made reverse domain "http://com.google" for April fools day 2015?

Tags: web, dns

You can find a reversed google page at https://com.google/.

As far I know, the domain name for ".google" sites does not exist.
I searched *who.i*s for it and the service tells that the domain "google" does not exist (as expected) - you can see it here: http://who.is/whois/com.google

My question is how did they do that!?

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/11/26/google_turns_on_google_internet_extension/

Comment: They bought the top level domain .google so that's why they are able to have domains such as com.google

Comment: [How come com.google is valid?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/78788/30516)

Comment: Simply because  the domain name for ".google" sites *does* exist. `.google` is a [valid top level domain name](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/google.html). Google registered it on 2014, Sep 4.